# Is PageRank a graph-based unsupervised learning algorithm?

Tags: graph, machine-learning, pagerank

From what I have read. PageRank is good example of Spectral clustering. If this is correct then PageRank can be dubbed as Unsupervised Learning on Graphs. Can anyone justify if PageRank is Unsupervised Learning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also consider PageRank as unsupervised because in PageRank algorithm, the objective is to minimize the difference between successive PageRank approximations.

On the other hand, I won't say PageRank is supervised because we are not given pages with pageranks as labels that can be used to build a model and predict new pageranks for test examples.

Comment: PageRank is an Unsupervised approach that is clear. But is it "Unsupervised Learning"? More specifically on graphs.

Comment: I consider it as unsupervised learning because I can't call it supervised!